# Nexus S: how can I control sites shown underneath stock browser search box?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, browser, samsung-nexus-s, stock-browser, browser-history

The built-in web browser of my Nexus S has a cool feature: when I press the Search button, in addition to a text box where I can type a URL or search terms, there are 4 sites shown above the on-screen keyboard.

How I can control what sites are listed?  I'd like to be able to populate that list with favorites so I can get one-click access to my top favorite sites without having to go through the "favorites" menu.

Answer (score 2):

It loads your most frequently visited websites. When you keep visiting a particular site lots of time (say like 3-4 times on the same day), then the site will get displayed in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the search button on *my* Nexus S, and indeed saw the four sites you mentioned.  I think they're some combination of bookmarks and history; I doubt that you can explicitly control them.